# Given $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$, is my calculation of $\det(-2B^T B A)$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $3 \times 3$ matrices with $\det(A) = -2$ and $\det(B) = -1$.
>
> What is the determinant of $C = -2 B^T B A$?

I know that
$$\det(A^T) = \det(A) \qquad \det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$$
so I got
$$\det(C) = -2(-1)(-1)(-2) = 4$$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Notice that for a matrix $A\in\mathcal M_n(\Bbb F)$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb F$
 we have

$$\det(\lambda A)=\lambda^n\det(A)$$

Comment: So the $-2$ coefficient turns into $(-2)^3$ when calculating determinant because $B^T$ has $n = 3$?  Thus $det(C) = (-2)^3*(-1)*(-1)*(-2) = 16$

Comment: What do $\mathcal M_n()$ and $\Bbb F$ mean?

Comment: $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb F)$ is the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients on the field $\Bbb F$.

Comment: Another way to think about it. The determinant of a matrix is the product of its singular values. When you multiply a matrix by a scalar, you multiply each of its singular values by this scalar. Hence, the result Sami is giving to you.

Comment: Another question, what if $A$ and $B$ had different $n$?  Which exponent would $\lambda$ have?

Comment: $\det(A)$ makes sense only for a square matrix. If $A$ and $B$ have different size then $AB$ exists only if the number of columns of $A$ is equal to the number of rows of $B$.